# catchup_by_default = False is ignored with DebugExecutor

Tags: python, airflow

I'm writing system tests for our airflow dag, it uses DebugExecutor to execute the dags end-to-end.

For this, I only want only one instance of the dag to run. However, I have so far failed to achieve it. Below are the some of things I tried.

In any of the below 2 cases, the backfill is triggered and multiple instances of dag run when `dag.run()`is invoked.

**airflow.cfg**

```
[core]
dags_folder = /code/bloodflow/dags
base_log_folder = /code/bloodflow/logs
plugins_folder = /code/bloodflow/plugins

load_examples = False
load_default_connections = False
colored_console_log = False
executor = DebugExecutor
logging_level = INFO
fernet_key = .............
catchup_by_default = False

[debug]
fail_fast = True

[secrets]
....

[webserver]
expose_config = True
dag_default_view = graph
dag_orientation = LR

[scheduler]
child_process_log_directory = /code/bloodflow/logs/scheduler
```

**test function**

```
def test(env_variables):
    from dags.sample import dag

    dag.clear(reset_dag_runs=True, start_date=dag.start_date)
    dag.run()

    assert dag.get_last_dagrun().get_state() == State.SUCCESS
    # other assertions
```

**test function version 1**

```
def test(env_variables):
    from dags.sample import dag

    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    dag.create_dagrun(
       run_id='manual__' + default_date.isoformat(),
       execution_date=now,
       state=State.RUNNING,
       external_trigger=True,
    )
    dag.run()

    assert dag.get_last_dagrun().get_state() == State.SUCCESS
```

Comment: Found any solution to this?

Comment: Try this 

```dag.clear()
        dag.run(executor=DebugExecutor(), start_date=dag.start_date, end_date=dag.start_date)

        # Validate DAG run was successful
        dagruns = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag.dag_id, execution_date=dag.start_date)
        assert len(dagruns) == 1
        assert dagruns[0].state == State.SUCCESS
`

https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-testing-skeleton/blob/4cc5e74e7cc8452677c1a9aa32b8917f8a822ddd/tests/test_airflow_full_dag.py#L30